# chrome spellcheck and different language for selected sites

Tags: google-chrome, browser, language, spell-check, dictionary

I was wondering if there is some way to make Chrome browser use different spellchecker dictionary for selected sites. I mostly write in Polish but on some sites I prefer to use English dictionary, so it would be very convenient to set English dictionary for SO and some more sites, but left Polish by default on other sites. There is also some inconvenience when changing dictionary in one browser tab since it changes on all other tabs.

Is this possible? Maybe there are some addons which can make it happen?